# PATH from docker env overwritten by Singularity when called by Snakemake

Tags: python, docker, snakemake, singularity-container

I am trying to use containers to run Snakemake pipelines, but the PATH variable keeps getting overwritten when Snakemake converts docker containers to singularity. Here is my dockerfile.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM mambaorg/micromamba@sha256:1dee8bc9409368d83d08b0a93370422a4fe0fd0092f56819bbf4c4cb254a8183
RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin
WORKDIR /usr/bin
RUN export PATH="$PATH:/opt/conda/bin"

ARG ENV_YML
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ${ENV_YML} /usr/bin/${ENV_YML}
RUN micromamba install -y -n base -f /usr/bin/${ENV_YML} && \
    micromamba clean --all --yes
```

The `$ENV_YML` simply has specifications for an environment. I have tried to manually add `/opt/conda/bin` to `PATH` even though for docker itself, I don't need it. This is where executables from the programs that micromamba installs goes (e.g. `reformat.sh`). I can open up docker `docker run -it --rm dockername/dockerfile:1.0.0` and run `reformat.sh` from anywhere because `/opt/conda/bin` is in the `PATH`. But when I try to run Snakemake using the docker I get `reformat.sh: file not found` error and thats because within the Singularity image the `/opt/conda/bin` is not in `PATH`. I can patch it by manually appending the folder to path like this in Snakefile:

```
# Snakefile
rule example:
    output:
      somefile.txt
    shell:
      """
      export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH && \
      (reformat.sh) 2> {log}
      """
```

But obviously I don't want to keep adding this code to all my rules. So how do I get singularity to not overwrite the `PATH` variable from docker?

Adding PATH explicitly to docker doesn't seem to work but adding it before executing in singularity does. So the file exists, its just that the `PATH` variable is overriden by user `PATH` variable in singularity, which is obviously an expected behavior on singularities end.

**Edit:** Some progress. If I use `--cleanenv` when running singularity then it seems to work e.g. `singularity run --cleanenv /path/to/image.simg` Inside that container instance all the path variables are set as they were in docker. Now I tried passing that as an arg via snakemake with:

```
snakemake --cores 1 --snakefile example/Snakefile --configfile config/config_test.yml --use-singularity --singularity-args "--cleanenv "
```

and that fails because I believe snakemake uses `singularity exec` under the hood.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Snakemake but I'm curious. Isn't it supposed to be like this: `shell: "export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH && (reformat.sh) 2> {log}"`, including the double quotes?

Comment: Thanks! Just fixed the quotes. Just forgot to copy that over from the actual code.

Comment: Oh okay, so it's not related to that. Also according to the [doc](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#environment-variables)s `this does not mean that Snakemake makes them available` which might be irrelevant but it's worth investigating. :^)